# Where in Android file system are directories created?

Tags: android

I am working on Android app that has to save data to files. To make the files accessible for all apps and also transfer to computer through USB, the files should be saved in a folder called "ABC". I manually created the folder "ABC" on both external storage card and internal storage. I was able to get full path of that folder on external storage card through code and was able to write and read from it.

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/ABC";
```

But the internal storage turns out to be more elusive because I could not get the full path of "ABC" folder on the internal storage. Is there a way to  programmatically determine where folders are created on internal storage? Generally, under what partion are folders created on internal storage in Android?

Edit: 
**Internal storage** - I mean non-removable storage 
**External Storage** - I mean Removable storage

Comment: I suggest to you to use: `File path = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "ABC" )` and then to retrive a string `file.getAbsolutePath()` - this also will show you the full path that you were asking

Answer (score 1):

> I manually created the folder "ABC" on both external storage card and internal storage.

You might have created this directory on [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html). Unless you are testing on a device or emulator, you did not create this directory on [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), as you do not have access to it. A "card" would imply [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html), which is something else entirely, for the vast majority of Android devices.

> I was able to get full path of that folder on external storage card through code and was able to write and read from it.

Your code is for external storage. On very few devices is that a "card".

> But the internal storage turns out to be more elusive because I could not get the full path of "ABC" folder on the internal storage.

There is no "ABC" folder on internal storage, insofar as you cannot create a `/ABC` directory off of the device root, or even off of `/data`. You can only work for your app's portion of internal storage, using methods like `getFilesDir()`. And, again, unless you are testing on an emulator or a rooted device, you have no means of creating such an "ABC" directory by hand.

> Is there a way to programmatically determine where folders are created on internal storage?

Um, well, you are certainly welcome to examine the path in the `File` object that you created to point to some location (e.g., `new File(getFilesDir(), "ABC")`).

> Generally, under what partion are folders created on internal storage in Android?

`/data`.

Comment: I see the confusion I created there. By external storage I mean removable storage like SD Cards. By Internal Storage I am referring to non-removable storage, not the Android definiton of Internal Storage. Thanks for pointing out my confusion and the clarification. Going back to the question, how can I access the folder I created on non-removable storage?

Comment: @birraa: "how can I access the folder I created on non-removable storage?" -- you already did, according to your question. `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` is non-removable storage, and more importantly, it is the only non-removable storage in which you can create an "ABC" directory from outside your app, which is my interpretation of "manually created".

Comment: It turns out on my phone, the default stroage location is set to SD Card and because of that, `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` was giving me the folder created on removable storage. When I set default storage to non-removable, `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`  is now giving me the "ABC" on non-removable storage.

Comment: @birraa: If you don't mind my asking, what device do you have that offers this capability? That's very unusual, and I might want to try to get one for my lab.

Comment: I am using Huawei G630-U10 phone.

Comment: Is there a way to differentiate between removable and non-removable storage in android code? If `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` refers to non-removable, how to indicate folder on removable?

Comment: @birraa: There is no Android SDK access to removable storage prior to [Android 4.4](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html). On Android 4.4+, you can use `getExternalFilesDirs()` (note the plural). If that returns 2+ items, the second and subsequent ones are places you can write on removable storage. Or, switch to the Storage Access Framework, and stop thinking about "files" as much as "streams", so the user can put the data anywhere (local file, Dropbox, Google Drive, etc.).

Comment: Thank you very much all especially @CommonsWare.